# Why don't webroot/.htaccess rules do apply to themes?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I added the following to the 'app/webroot/.htaccess' file to enable a far future expires header for resource files such as .css and .js. While this works fine for any content served out of the /js /css /img folders, it will not apply to anything placed in a CakePHP theme webroot/js|css|img folder.

Is there a similar method that should be used to control resource caching from themes? All of my theme resource files expire the next day as if its grabbing some sort of default.

There are no other Apache rules in place for mod_expires as I'm trying to keep it all in .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"

    # ... Also added png,js etc...

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default settings of CakePHP, themed (and plugin-) assets are served via PHP, not directly handled by Apache. I'm not 100% sure, but this probably causes the htaccess settings not to be applied, because Apache does not see those files as 'static' files.

For a production site, it is advisable to change the settings, as is described here [Increasing performance of plugin and theme assets](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html#increasing-performance-of-plugin-and-theme-assets)

### Additional tips on performance

As a side-note, for additional performance;

- Have a look at the Server configuration files of Html5 Boilerplate. They are *very well documented* and offer a lot of valuable settings to speed up the performance of your website. A lot of research has been put into those settings, so that you dont have to do that yourself. Many of those settings also apply to CakePHP websites. You can find the configuration files here: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/tree/master/apache
- Don't use .htaccess files, but move all rules/settings of your .htaccess files to your VirtualHost configuration and disable override. This way, Apache doesn't have to scan every directory for possible .htaccess files for each request

Comment: Sym-linking the Theme webroot js,css, and img folders solved this. The following commands will enable this.

`cd app/weboot`
`mkdir theme`
`cd theme`
`mkdir MyTheme`
`cd MyTheme`
`ln -s ../../../View/Themed/MyTheme/webroot/js "js"`
`ln -s ../../../View/Themed/MyTheme/webroot/css "css"`
`ln -s ../../../View/Themed/MyTheme/webroot/img "img"`

Next step is to create a git post-merge hook to do this on Production servers...

Comment: @carcus88 You may also be able to get this working via mod_alias or mod_rewrite from within the vhost file; if your vhost is inside your GitHub repository, a simple 'reload' of Apache may do the trick after updating your production server. Anyway, glad you got it working!